# Magento Invalidated BLock Cache

Tags: magento

I am monitoring Magento store and have observed that my "Blocks HTML output" cache is invalidated after few hours and then I have to refresh it to make it enable.

I am not sure why I am getting this "Invalidated Cache" error message, even though I have not made any changes on site. Is it because one of the block output is not correct? If so, how can I identify such block?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check this link :
[What does "invalidated" cache mean in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423604/what-does-invalidated-cache-mean-in-magento)

Brief explanation :
Magento caches blocks.

When some products are updated then blockc cached will not have those updated details hence Magento shows this, indicating that these blocks are not to the mark and action needs to be taken.

Comment: I am pretty sure, that their are no product or static block are not updates, even after that it still show invalidated cache.